# generate all combinations of a variable number of vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, combinations

I am looking for a method of generating a matrix that contains all the combinations of vectors in MATLAB, like below

```
>> combvec(1:3,2:4)

ans =

     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     2     2     2     3     3     3     4     4     4
```

As we can see, the example above is given two vectors, i.e., `1:3` and `2:4`. However, if we have a ***variable number of vectors***, e.g., `v1,v2,...vn` (***where `n` is not given***), then how can we generate all combinations?

For instance, given `v1,v2,...vn`, is there any way of generating the same result as `combvec(v1,v2,...vn)` but without writting down all `n` vectors (since `n` might be a large number and varying each time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack a cell with `mycell{:}`, if passed as an argument; each element of the cell will be interpreted as a new argument:

```
v1 = [1,2,3];
v2 = [2,3,4];
v3 = [3,4,5];

% We put everything in a cell
v = {v1,v2,v3};

% We unpack our cell into combvec
combvec(v{:})
```

Of course this example is pretty useless, but in a real case situation you can simply store your vectors directly in a cell `v{ii} = ...`